# creating error labels like jquery validate after server side validation

Tags: jquery

I am returning a JSON from my validation CFC, which contains an array of fields that were found to be in error.

```
{"error":1,"fields":["first_name","email","last_name","comments"]}
```

I am using the jquery post method, but when I get the data returned, I cannot create the labels based on the fields in the json.

```
$.each(data.fields, function(){
    $("#" + this + "\"").append("<label class='error' for='" + this + "'>Please check your input</label>")
```

But this doesn't appear to work. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I am using jquery validation plugin, but I am required to use server side validation as well.  I have disabled the validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a backslash (`\`) to your selector which will make your selector fail. Remove the backslash (i.e., `$("#" + this)`) and it should work.

On another note, the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) uses the `name` attribute for validation, not the `id` attribute, so unless your server-side validation is returning the `id` attribute you're going to want to use a selector that targets the `name` attribute instead.

```
var selector = 'input[name="' + this + '"], textarea[name="' + this + '"]',
    field = $(selector);
field.after($('<label />').attr('for', field.attr('id')).addClass('error').text('Please check your input'));
```

Or use this to target the `id` attribute:

```
var selector = '#' + this,
    field = $(selector);
$(selector).after($('<label />').attr('for', field.attr('id')).addClass('error').text('Please check your input'));
```

**Here's a fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/aHLgw/**

Finally, while there's technically nothing wrong with using the `this` keyword, it would be a better practice to use the `key` and `value` parameters as it will more clearly indicate to others who may have to maintain the code you write that you are iterating through an object or an array, instead of a DOM Element Collection.

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly as intended.  I have always struggled with variables as jQuery selectors.  I have also changed it to use the name attribute, because the name and id are the same, and I have changed it to use the key/value pairing as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two things :

- You need to pass two parameters to `each`. `this` will return a string of arrays. So, consider I'm logging `this` and the `parameters` passed to `each`.

  ```
  $.each(data.fields, function (key, value) {
    console.log("when this is used - a string array: ",this);
    console.log("value (parameter passed to each) is used - string : ", value);
  });
  ```

  Here's the console output for the following code (when "comments" string is in scope)

  [image: Console output]
  More info at docs : http://api.jquery.com/each/
- `$("#" + value + "\"")` won't work here. Just `$("#" + value)` would do.

  ```
  $.each(data.fields, function (key, value) {
     $("#" + value).append("<label class='error' for='" + value + "'>Please check your input</label>")
  });
  ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Use `this.text()`, that will return the actual value of the elements or use a callback function as told by hungerpain above.